# A strange result about `parseStringStyle` in Vue3' s source code

Tags: vuejs3

I am studying Vue3 source code recently, one expression makes me really confusing

here it is:

```
  const propertyDelimiterRE = /:(.+)/;
  "color:red;".split(propertyDelimiterRE);// ["color", "red;", ""]
```

I

```js
const propertyDelimiterRE = /:(.+)/;
const parseResult = "color:red;".split(propertyDelimiterRE);
console.log(parseResult)
```

don't know why is that, please help me thanks

Comment: what didn't you understand the syntax or the output?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I think the delimiter is ":red;" so I suppose it will return ["color",""], But it is not. I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

this is more of a `split` + regex question, but here it goes

The regular expression portion `:(.+)` has two parts, `:` and `(.+)`

`:` says to watch for the `:` character literally

`(.+)` says to capture any character(s) except for line terminators

so together, they will capture `:red;` (full match) and `red;` as the capture group.

The second part is that the way [split behaves] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#description)

> *When found, separator is removed from the string, and the substrings are returned in an array.*
>
> *If separator is a regular expression with capturing parentheses, then each time separator matches, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are **spliced into the output array**.*

so togeter...

- `"color:red;".split( /:(.+)/)` will use `:` and everything after it to split the string
- that will be (sort of) equivalent of `"color:red;".split(":red;)`
- which would return `["color", ""]`
- however, because we're using a split with capture group, it *splices* the matched capture group into the array, giving us `["color", ":red;", ""]`